# How to Display data with 'yes' or 'no' entries unique.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my data

```
unitCode stunum assNo   subStatus 
SIT111  1000    1   Yes
SIT111  1000    2   No
SIT111  3000    1   No
```

How do i generate only results with ONLY a  'No'

eg: Only student 3000 should come up. Since that person has not handed in ANY assignments. ?

Comment: Please use the `[sql-server]` tag instead of separate `sql` and `server` tags - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following statement:

```
select
    *
from
(
    select
        unitCode,
        stunum,
        sum(case when subStatus = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as CountYes,
        sum(case when subStatus = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as CountNo
    from
        students
    group by
        unitCode, stunum
) as student
inner join student_details
    on student.stunum = student_details.stunum
where
    CountNo > 0 and CountYes = 0;
```

Comment: @David: I know. That was Oracle code. I updated my answer already, please check.

Comment: How would i join another table and use columns from that.. eg student details?

Comment: @David: It depends. If you need these details to determine the number of handed in assignments, you would need to add the join to the inner select. If you need these details for all students that didn't hand it an assignment, add the join to the outer select.

Comment: eg, lets say there is a table with the student details, i want to join it to this table so i can generate their first name and last name along with unitCode, stunum, countYes, CountNo

Comment: Not valid in SQL Server. `&&` should be `and`. Derived tables require aliases and `sum(case ... ))` has too many closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  unitCode varchar(10),
  stunum int,
  assNo int,
  subStatus varchar(3)
)  

insert into @T values
('SIT111',  1000,    1,   'Yes'),
('SIT111',  1000,    2,   'No'),
('SIT111',  3000,    1,   'No')

select *
from @T as T
where T.subStatus = 'No' and
      T.stunum not in (select stunum
                       from @T
                       where subStatus = 'Yes')
```